# invalid syntax on return line at python

Tags: python, syntax, return, syntax-error

I get an invalid syntax on return at this code:

```
def readDataSet(filename):

    fr = open(filename)                 

    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines()) 

    returnMat = numpy.zeros((numberOfLines-1,3)) 

    classLabelVector = [] 
    classColorVector = [] 


    fr = open(filename) 
    index = 0

    for line in fr.readlines():  
        if index != 0:           
            line = line.strip()
            listFromLine = line.split('\t') 

            returnMat[index-1,:] = listFromLine[1:4] 

            classLabel = listFromLine[4]  

            if classLabel == "Buero":
                color = 'yellow'
            elif classLabel == "Wohnung":
                color = 'red'
            else:
                color = 'blue'

            classLabelVector.append(classLabel) 
            classColorVector.append(color)       

        index += 1


return returnMat,classLabelVector, classColorVector
```

It says that the return has the wrong syntax, but I don't know where the error is.

Comment: please intent your return statement, it should be inside `def`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add indentation to your return. Return statement is at the same level as definition of function now it has to be inside the function defenition

```
def readDataSet(filename):

    fr = open(filename)                 

    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines()) 

    returnMat = numpy.zeros((numberOfLines-1,3)) 

    classLabelVector = [] 
    classColorVector = [] 


    fr = open(filename) 
    index = 0

    for line in fr.readlines():  
        if index != 0:           
            line = line.strip()
            listFromLine = line.split('\t') 

            returnMat[index-1,:] = listFromLine[1:4] 

            classLabel = listFromLine[4]  

            if classLabel == "Buero":
                color = 'yellow'
            elif classLabel == "Wohnung":
                color = 'red'
            else:
                color = 'blue'

            classLabelVector.append(classLabel) 
            classColorVector.append(color)       

        index += 1
    return returnMat,classLabelVector, classColorVector
```